# Why can [SomeClass class] return null in main.m

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make an iOS app without using xibs or storyboards. So my `main.m` 
looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

If I check value of `[AppDelegate class]` it is `(null)`. 
So the question is, why?
Also if i check [NSString class] or other class from standard library it performs normally.
I thought that file is not in `Compile sources` list, but it's there. This problem only occurs in one project.

Comment: I don't see where you call `[AppDelegate class]`. Or where you declare and alloc/init `pionersAppDelegate`.

Comment: You could always hardcode the class name - but the problem is weird.

Comment: Is `AppDelegate` part of your target and correctly compiled?

Comment: How are you checking the value of [AppDelegate class]? Is the app otherwise working correctly?

Comment: @picciano `NSLog(@"%@",[AppDelegate class]);` No i had other problems with this project, but this problem does not let me even launch it.

Comment: Is your app crashing?

Comment: @anum90 yes it says `Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch`

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have initialized assigned some controller to your window's root controller in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8188159/437146) answer.

Comment: I can't do this, my AppDelegate must be initialized first.

Comment: @SatansDeer R u sure AppDelegate is the main class which is going to handle your application? Or you changed something?

Comment: Yes, i'm totally sure. Also this AppDelegate behaves normally in another project i created for testing purpose.

Comment: Alright. have you checked using breakpoint that `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is really not been called?