# UITableView not bouncing and cells not being selected

Tags: objective-c

First of all, I know this question has already been asked but the answer did not solve my problem.

So, Im in XCode 4.2. I am loading a table View and trying to select a row. The row does not seem to be selected. I also tried NSlogging in the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}
```

but the method is not called at all. Also, the table does not bounce.

FYI, I have set the bounce and selection properties in IB.

Can someone please help me out?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the delegate of your table view to whichever class has didSelectRowAtIndexPath defined, something like:

```
sometableview.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply. I had done all you suggested, but, I overlooked the warning that I was receiving all along

    "Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"

As soon as got rid of it, everything worked like a charm.
Incase anyone else has the same problem, here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520971/applications-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-applicati)