# Why is my core data tutorial application opening with a black screen and no tableview?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm following [Apple's Core Data Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH1-SW1) for iOS and am having issues pretty early on when I have to build the application for the first time at the [Build and Test](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/02_RootViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH104-SW9) step.

I'm building this with Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5.

[Here is my source](http://d.pr/qEYZ)

[image: And a screenshot of what is appearing]

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520971/applications-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-applicati

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't create the app window.

Add this line:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

on the top of

```
application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem! I wonder why the tutorial doesn't have that line of code.

Comment: 6 months later, and that tutorial is still broken. Thanks for this answer (and the question, too, obviously)