# how to come out this situation

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520971/applications-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-applicati)

I working on a splash screen in that new subclass tableview included in window, I got this type of runtime error"Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"

any suggestion and source.

Answer (score 0):

It's harmless if your next viewController is being invoked.  I've tracked this down and the issue is that if the method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions completes prior to the setting of the property, the runtime throws this error.

I have apps that must validate the user before loading a viewController so this property is set later with no harm.