# Setting tabBarController.selectedIndex/selectedViewController when it's a UINavigationController

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I've got 5 views in my tabBarController and all of them are embedded in a separate navigationcontroller, i.e. every view has it's own navigationcontroller. I did this to make it easier to push segues, I know it's probably not the best solution but it works fine. Now to my question:

I'm trying to set the initial view with the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
    return YES;
}
```

However it's not working at all, the app simply starts and index 0 (the left most view).

I've searched through thorough threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520971/applications-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-applicati?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) and tried many different ways to solve this without any success...

Closest I got was when I in MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard checked the box "Is initial view controller" in the viewcontroller I want to start with. This way the I got the correct starting viewcontroller but the tabbar wasn't showing.

Comment: Try logging your tabBarController to make sure its not NULL, what does this return NSLog(TBC : %@, tabBarController); ? Add this log statement in your appDelegate didFinishLaunching: method

Comment: Well you know you stuff sir, it returns "tabgaze[46885:c07] TBC : (null)". Does this mean I have to initialize the tabBarController and programmatically add the 5 viewcontrollers? It feels like everything is being intitiated twice that way since I'm using storyboard? Perhaps I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using storyboard, do this : 
1) Give your tabBarController a storyboard identifier (say tbc);
2) In your appDelegate DidFinishLaunching, do this ::

```
UITabBarController *tbc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tbc"];

[tbc setSelectedIndex:1];
[self.window setRootViewController:tbc];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

PS : This is just one of many ways to make it work

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much! If anyone runs into the same problem I just realized that the "Identifier" in storyboard in Xcode 4.5 is called "Storyboard ID".