# Strange behaviour when initialising UISegmentedControl

Tags: c#, ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

I'm writing a MonoTouch app and I'm trying to add a UISegmentedControl to a View (programmatically not through IB). I kept receiving the following error message:

```
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

This is strange because a UISegmentedControl has nothing to do with the Window root view controller. In the end I reduced the code all the way down to the initialisation of the variable:

```
// This code appears in a class which inherits from UIView
var segmentedControl = new UISegmentedControl ();
```

I've tried putting this code in a class that inherits from UIViewController and the same behaviour occurred. I even tried putting it into the AppDelegate but still the same error was displayed.

**NOTE: I am debugging on an iPad device when running this code**

After playing around I eventually commented out a random UIViewController class that I have and the app ran fine. I've tried commenting out various different UIViewControllers and every time it runs fine so there's not one view controller which seems to be the problem. It's as if I've hit some sort of limit to the amount of view controllers that I can have.

Is this possible? And if not what might the problem be?

P.S. This may be related to a previous issue that I raised here: [Error when adding UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741506/error-when-adding-uitabbarcontroller)

**EDIT**

Inside the FinishedLaunching method I have this code:

```
_window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
_window.RootViewController = _navigationController;
_window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
```

I am running this in iOS version 6.1.

I've since tried commenting out any class not just one that inherits from UIViewController, and the app runs fine. Perhaps it is a memory issue

**EDIT 2**

I tried removing the view and controller from where this was being affected and built them again and drilled it down to when the view inherits from UIView. If I have that code in the UIViewController and a class which will be used as a UIView (but not actually inherit from it) then the app runs without a problem. As soon as I inherit that class from UIView I get the error message described above.

Answer (score 0):

That error is not related with `UISegmentedControl`. Please check whether you mentioned application's rootview in your code. If not do it.

In the `FinishedLaunching` method add:

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (5, 0))
{
   window.RootViewController = yourViewController;
}
else
{
   window.AddSubview (yourViewController.View);
}
```

Comment: If I remove to the UISegmentedControl initialisation then the app runs fine even with all the view controllers there. The root view controller on the Window is set in AppDelegate

Comment: Tried that and I still get the same issue. I've updated my original post

Comment: @Serberuss: Check whether your `_navigationController` is nil or not

Comment: It's initialised fine. I haven't had a problem running the app up until this point

Comment: @Serberuss: there is no limit for viewcontrollers and views (Untill the memory is full). I'm not expert in MOnotouch, but I have seen the issue in iOS, I fixed it by setting the rootViewController.