# Root View Controller at End of Application Launch

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know there are a lot of these out there, but none of the solutions have worked for me.

Here is the situation:

`AppDelegate.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SphereViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SphereViewController *sphereViewController;

@end
```

`AppDelegate.m`

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.sphereViewController = [[SphereViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SphereViewController" bundle:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@", self.sphereViewController);

    self.window.rootViewController = self.sphereViewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

...

@end
```

When running this code the following is logged:

```
2014-01-04 21:21:18.691 Sphere[4978:70b] <SphereViewController: 0x10931c600>
2014-01-04 21:25:25.145 Sphere[4978:70b] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

Why am I getting the root view controller error even though I am setting it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520971/applications-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-applicati)

Comment: @kkocabiyik As I have stated I have read that post and have not been successful.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard? To put it another way: did you start with a template that has a main.storyboard?

Comment: @matt No I am using nibs (started with Empty Application)

Comment: The long delay is really suspicious. It should not take that long to launch your app (in fact, your app can be killed for taking this long to launch). I think you should reread the recommended linked answer and its accompanying comments. Perhaps either you are not using the app delegate you think you are, or something else is happening you aren't showing that is causing some other window, without a root view controller, to take over as the app's main window. Something is very wrong with the fundamental structure of your app project.

Comment: @matt Thanks for pointing out the long delay had not noticed that before. `main.m` is calling the correct `AppDelegate`. I have no idea why something else would be taking it over (it is almost a brand new project). Also the `initWithNibName...` is default code (created by apple). What would cause this long of a delay?

Comment: Perhaps it is something that SphereViewController does that is the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44535/discussion-between-matt-and-cabellicar123)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that for some reason the `view` property for the File's Owner in my xib was set to a GLKView which apparently causes this error.

To fix make sure your `view` property is linked correctly.

Comment: Just to clarify: It turned out that the .xib contained a normal view with a GLKView inside it. The File's Owner's `view` outlet was hooked to the GLKView. Hooking it to the superview (the normal view) instead, solved the launch problem. It is easy to hook your `view` outlet to the wrong view accidentally. I do not know why doing so caused this particular launch issue, but at least we solved it.