# Error message about having a root view controller at the end of application launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

There are some questions on Stack Overlow regarding this error, but none of the solutions seemed to work for me. Would someone be able to glance at my code and see why I am getting the following error?

> Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h" //import header file

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController* viewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController"];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Update your question by pasting in (and formatting) the relevant code.

Comment: Wouldn't it be neater to just do what I did?

Comment: Questions on SO need to be self-contained so they remain useful in the future. Please include the _minimum_ code necessary to reproduce the problem, not a link, and not all your code. Also, given that this has been asked many times, please explain in more detail what you've tried and why the other solutions didn't work for you.

Comment: Please let me know if any of the other files are required for help in the debugging process. I tried the solutions from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520971/applications-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-applicati?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `rootViewController` to `self.viewController` but you never set `self.viewController`.

Try this:

```
self.viewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController"];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```