# Cannot set root view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, view, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I keep getting the warning

```
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

Ive been looking for a fix but all the solutions I found matched my code.
Thanks in advance its probably something simple but i've been stuck on it for awhile now.

AppDelegate.m

```
self.rootController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

DownloadTableView *view2 = [[DownloadTableView alloc] init];
view2 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"DownloadTableView" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Download"];

TableViewController *view3 = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
view3 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"table"];

appWebView = [[WebViewController alloc] init];

view3.tabBarItem.title = @"Documents";
appWebView.title = @"Browser";
view2.title = @"Downloads";

self.rootController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:appWebView, view2, view3,  nil];
self.window.rootViewController = _rootController; 

appWebView.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Browser.png"];
view2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Download.png"];

_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// [_window addSubview:_rootController.view];
[_window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Which method are you implementing with the code above? Why are you setting the root view controller twice? Why are you unnecessarily adding the controller's view as a subview after setting it as the root controller (see the documentation for `rootViewController`)?

Comment: I cleaned the code up and edited my post I am still getting the warning though

Comment: Well now you create a new window, never set its root view controller, and then make it the key window. It shouldn't be surprising that this warns you the root view controller has not been set.

Answer (score 0):

Few lines seems to be redundant which might cause issue, pointed o -

```
self.rootController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

DownloadTableView *view2 = [[DownloadTableView alloc] init];
view2 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"DownloadTableView" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Download"];

TableViewController *view3 = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
view3 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"table"];

view3.tabBarItem.title = @"Documents";

appWebView = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
appWebView.title = @"Browser";
appWebView.tabBarItem.title = @"Browser";

view2.title = @"Downloads";
self.rootController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:appWebView, view2, view3,  nil];

self.window.rootViewController = self.rootController; <-----

appWebView.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Browser.png"];
view2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Download.png"];

_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[_window addSubview:_rootController.view]; <-------
[_window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Still getting the warning

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520971/applications-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-applicati

Answer (score 0):

Is all this code called in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method? Is **_window** field connected to **window** property?

P.S. There are a lot of useless and weird lines, as well.

Comment: Yes thats all in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
@property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window; is in the header

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out this morning when I woke up

```
_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Was unnecessary and was conflicting with the tab bar