# White screen when launched in build

Tags: xcode

Whenever i launch an app with text, i get a white screen (there is 1 more scene). i have tried remaking it and deleting this code. It is on X code and started from the preset "empty Application"

```
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

GOt this is in debugging

2014-07-18 11:20:43.821 Wallpaper[7635:60b] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

i expected to see a table saying address and all i saw was a white screen. Any reason known?

Comment: Can you expand on "It didn't work"? Please explain 1) what you expected, and 2) what you saw instead. If there is an error message, show that too. Don't reply in comments - edit your question to add it.

Comment: Alright i did that Thanks for the feedback @TarynEast

Comment: Have you googled for that error message? What did you find? :)

Comment: i found this page @TarynEast

Comment: Of course you found this page - you wrote this page ;) What *else* did you find ;)

Comment: Because I found this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520971/applications-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-applicati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your UIWindow is missing a root view controller, i.e:

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
```

Comment: where did you put it, should be before makeKeyAndVisible.

Comment: `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen             mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;`

Comment: could you up this really need reputation for another question i have