# How is My app's orientation is Landscape,but the pixels are portrait?

Tags: ios, xcode, orientation, landscape, portrait

[image]

This problem happened on my iOS app, as the figure showed. The screen Orientation didn't match with my app.
Is there any way I can look at? Where should I look up for this kind of problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you define your window in a xib file, make sure the "Full Screen At Launch
" checkbox is checked for that window in the settings inspector.  Also, if you;r app launches into landscape you should create the window in code or migrate to a storyboard as there are bugs with xib files + launching to landscape.

Beyond that, possible explanations are that you're doing silly things such as modifying view transforms or spawning secondary windows.

Comment: Hi, my app is based on EAGLView. And I am sure that the xib file's setting is fine. The content on the screen is not just "Full Screen", but also ROTATED. How is that happened? I am using glviewport(0,0,960,640) as long as the Orientation set to be Landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out I had came across an error"Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch" error. Fixed it by the method of [Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520971/applications-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-applicati).