# In Xcode 7, iOS 9 "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got an error in my console and crash.

```
“Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch”
```

Below is my piece of code, after enter the return YES line crash will happens.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    

    UIImageView *defaultImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:splashImage];
    defaultImage.frame = defaultImageFrame;
    [self.window addSubview:defaultImage];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self
                                   selector:@selector(login:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    return YES; // here crash will happens
}


-(void)login:(id)sender
{
   PreLoginViewController *appController = [[PreLoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
            if (_ChooseLogin.isStatus == 105)
            {
                flagRequired = @"1";
                appController.serverDownFlag = @"1";
            }
            appController.termsURL = _ChooseLogin.urlString;

            appController._ChooseLogin = _ChooseLogin;
            appController.rootNetworkAvailable = NO;
            appController.verionMsg = versionStr;
            [dft setBool:NO forKey:@"isNeedActivate"];
            appController.isNeedActivate = NO;
            navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                    initWithRootViewController:appController];

}
```

Any one know how to fix this issue? its workes fine in iOS 8, upto Xcode 6.3.

Comment: If you are using beta 5, try using `bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]` instead of `bundle:nil`

Comment: its not entering into login function @Vin

Comment: Where did you call login function?

Comment: in the interval of 3.0 in NSTimer @ErsinSezgin

Comment: Have you tried it without timer?

Comment: ya. But there is no change crash will occur with the same error. @ErsinSezgin

Comment: ok Thnks. I'll try in this way. But it didn't get any error till now. Its working fine when i run my project in earlier version of xcode that is 6.x except xcode 7.0. @Desdenova

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch" error when running a project with Xcode 7, iOS 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884896/application-windows-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-a)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to call `setRootViewController`: in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`: and you need a view controller to do this.

In code:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[vc.view addSubview:defaultImage]; 
[self.window setRootViewController:vc];
```

Comment: BTW, if you create several windows within your app - all of them must have assigned rootViewController at the end of application launch (in IOS 9)