# Splash screen animation is not supporting with Xcode 7 GM(iOS9). App crashes with an error

Tags: objective-c, animation, ios9, xcode7

In my application i am using the below code to show an animated splash screen. App working fine in Xcode-6.4(iOS 8), but coming to Xcode-7GM version(iOS9) app crashes with an error.

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:IMAGE_COUNT];
    // Build array of images, cycling through image names
    for (int i = 1; i <= IMAGE_COUNT; i++)
     [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:
                               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image__%d.png",i]]];
    animationImageView  = [[UIImageView alloc]  initWithFrame:self.window.bounds];
    animationImageView  .animationImages=[NSArray arrayWithArray:imageArray];
    // One cycle through all the images takes 3.5 seconds
    animationImageView .animationDuration = 3.5;
    // Repeat forever
    animationImageView  .animationRepeatCount = 0;
    // Add subview and make window visible
    [window addSubview:animationImageView  ];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    // Start it up animations
    [animationImageView   startAnimating];
    // Wait 3.5 seconds, then stop animation
   [self performSelector:@selector(stopAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.5];`
```

This is the error message what i am getting while using Xcode-7GM:

> Assertion failure in -[UIApplication
>   _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:],
>        /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3505.16/UIApplication.m:3294

Comment: That is not the _whole_ error message. There was an assertion failure. What _is_ the assertion failure?

Comment: This is the whole error message i seen in the log   :                               2015-09-14 10:11:59.073 appname[721:11491] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
2015-09-14 10:11:59.441 appname[721:11367] *** Assertion failure in -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3505.16/UIApplication.m:3294

Comment: Really? It says "assertion failure" but it doesn't tell you what the assertion _is_ (no assertion message)? That is very odd. However, it sounds, from `kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL`, like the problem has to do with networking. Are you doing some sort of networking during launch? (Bad idea.) And did you remember that in iOS 9, by default, you can only do `https:`?

Comment: i also get this error :-"Assertion failure in -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3505.16/UIApplication.m:3294" how to solve this error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

change to

```
    [window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to do some networking. In iOS 9, by default, all network communication must be secure. If you are trying to do an `http:` request, it will fail; you must use `https:` (unless you switch this feature off in your *Info.plist*).

Comment: In my experience you'll actually get an App Transport Security warning in the console if this is the case.

Comment: @race_carr Sometimes. :) But I've also seen it just fail silently.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, It has been solved by replacing the below line of code in `Appdelegate.m`

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

with

```
[window setRootViewController:viewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it has been solved by removing        [window makeKeyAndVisible];.

The self window needs to be set as root view controller in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: :
    [self.window setRootViewController:navController];

Answer (score 0):

For me like jonmo,  this error was the result of not defining rootViewController prior to exiting didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Doing so resolved this issue for me.

Prior to Xcode 7, it was just a warning now it seems to be a hard stop

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution to this error message was updating an included CocoaPods dependency called [Loopback](https://lookback.io/changelog) (that I believe adds an extra UIWindow to the app.)