# xamarin error : NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to reorganize an old application written in Xamarin. The application gives the following error without opening the application in the simulator. Can you help me?

**Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch**
Native stack trace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20421af6 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177e78 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2042191f +[NSException raise:format:] + 0
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff2077156a -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 191
4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2469a8fc -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2148
5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23cc36f7 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 122
6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24251d1e _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 88
7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23cc4206 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 198
8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23cc3cca -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 474
......
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSzZC.png)

Comment: Do you develop the app in xamarin.forms or xamarin.ios?

Comment: Please dont create code images. Its a violation of SO guidelines. You can easily write your code in SO with markdown.

Comment: xamarin.ios develop

Answer (score 0):

iOS9 requires all the Window must have a rootViewController, you should edit AppDelegate like this:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            // If not required for your application you can safely delete this method

            var indexVC = new IndexViewController ();
            window = new UIWindow ((CGRect)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
            window.RootViewController = indexVC;
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();


            return true;
        }
```

you can refer to [this page](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/52834/application-windows-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-application-launch) for more details.

There are some changes since ios9, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32538671/splash-screen-animation-is-not-supporting-with-xcode-7-gmios9-app-crashes-wit/32719949#32719949) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884896/application-windows-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-a) page

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for the reply.

I am still having the problem, I couldn't able to solve it.

Comment: var indexVC = new customViewController();
window = new UIWindow((CGRect)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
window.RootViewController = indexVC;
window.MakeKeyAndVisible(); 
public partial class customViewController: UIViewController
{

 public customViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
 {
   
 }

  
 public customViewController(NSCoder coder) : base(coder)
 {
 }
 public customViewController() : base("customViewController", null)
 {   
 }
  
 public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
 {
 return true;
 }
}