# iOS 9 Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Tags: ios9, xcode7, launching-application

enter link description hereI run my project in xocde 6.4 successfully,when I updated to Xcode7 Im getting error at launch.

[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3505.16/UIApplication.m:3294
2015-09-19 12:16:48.889 OrderEm[4102:68071] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'

```
  -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
 self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]autorelease];


 Login *login=[[[Login alloc]initWithNibName:@"Login~iPad" bundle:nil]autorelease];

        [self.window setRootViewController:login];
       // self.window.rootViewController = login;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        return YES;
 }
```

My login view didload and viewwillappear methods called after that getting this crash.

Comment: Having same issue on update, find anything out?

Comment: It seems only occuring some times

Comment: NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
        for(UIWindow *window in windows) {
            NSLog(@"window: %@",window.description);
            if(window.rootViewController == nil){
                UIViewController* vc = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
                window.rootViewController = vc;
            }
Its worked for me ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch" error when running a project with Xcode 7, iOS 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884896/application-windows-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-a)

Answer (score 3):

This fixed it for me

[Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520971/applications-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-applicati/32680220#32680220)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this error, returns this error in the simulator, there is no problem on the real machine.

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3505.16/UIApplication.m:3294
```

Comment: @duxinfend my app got rejected twice because of this same reason advice don't take it lightly