# Assertion error in App Delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, xcode 7, ios 9

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode7

2015-09-28 23:46:57.711 app[77230:1354628] *** Assertion failure in -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3505.16/UIApplication.m:3294
2015-09-28 23:46:57.714 app[77230:1354628] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'

```
    let cvc = ContainerViewController()
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window!.rootViewController = cvc
    return true
```

I know many people got the same error but I spent one frustrate night to fix for this error but no luck. Is there any way that we can set rootViewController for window in AppDelegate here ?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884896/application-windows-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-a

Comment: can you be more specific, I already tried many approach in the link but nothing worked so far . Thanks !