# "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller" message when adding view immediately after launch, iOS 9 only

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios9, uiapplicationdelegate

My app sends a request at startup and displays a brief message to users when it succeeds, by means of [`MTStatusBarOverlay`](https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay). Unfortunately, my current implementation seems to run afoul of iOS 9's view life cycle paradigms. I get the message

> Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

and the app crashes. The app works fine on iOS 7 & 8.

From searching around online, it seems like this might occur when trying to add the message view to the view hierarchy before the root view controller is established for the app's `UIWindow`, but that doesn't seem to be the case here, see below.

Here is an excerpt of the `UIApplicationDelegate` implementation:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [...]

    self.window.rootViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

    [...]
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [MyDataManager sendRequestWithCompletion:^{
        // Displays a message with MTStatusBarOverlay
        [self showSuccessOverlay];
    }];
}
```

`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is called before `applicationDidBecomeActive:` so it seems like there should never be an issue with `rootViewController` being established.

Why is this happening? What's different about iOS 9 that's causing the app to break?

Comment: Possibbly related to this issue https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7074. Also you can check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884896/application-windows-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MTStatusBarOverlay` is a subclass of `UIWindow`, so instantiating one during app launch adds that `UIWindow` to the list that iOS checks for a populated `rootViewController` when launch completes.

I was able to work around the issue by instantiating and assigning a dummy controller before using the overlay, like so:

```
[MTStatusBarOverlay sharedInstance].rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
[[MTStatusBarOverlay sharedInstance] postMessage:@"Message"];
```