# App crashes only in review, is this a keychain issue?

Tags: ios, crash, keychain, review

Can't duplicate the crash on my devices, and I don't understand this entry in the crash log:

2015-11-27 13:43:34.361 LARSA[1453]:   SecOSStatusWith error:[-25299] Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-25299 "duplicate item O,genp,38C76CFA,L,ak,K95FHDJ5ZD.studiosixdigital,0,acct,svce,gena,v_Data,20151127214334.356112Z,0066C90F" UserInfo={NSDescription=duplicate item O,genp,38C76CFA,L,ak,K95FHDJ5ZD.studiosixdigital,0,acct,svce,gena,v_Data,20151127214334.356112Z,0066C90F}

Seems to be a duplicate item of some kind, but where?

Comment: Did you set both kSecAttrAccount and kSecAttrService? http://useyourloaf.com/blog/keychain-duplicate-item-when-adding-password.html

Comment: Yes, and the odd thing is that the keychain code that I am running is shared by about a dozen apps, and only 2 of them are failing in review. The rest all passed. So I am suspecting some difference in the plist files or something. Just not sure if the "duplicated item" message has any meaning that might help me.

Comment: So it was really this line that related to the crash:
Assertion failure in -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:]

Answer (score 0):

So it was not the KeyChain at all, it was apparently some window that was not connected to a viewcontroller. This code fixed it in diFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
    NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];     // wow some crazy fix....
for(UIWindow *window in windows) {
    NSLog(@"window: %@",window.description);
    if(window.rootViewController == nil){
        UIViewController* vc = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        window.rootViewController = vc;
    }
}
```

Which I found on this StackOverflow post:

[Application windows are expected to have root view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884896/application-windows-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-a)