# 'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow

Why do I add

```
static UIWindow *window_;
window_ = [[UIWindow alloc]init];
window_.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, XMGScreenW, 20);
window_.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
window_.hidden = NO;
```

to `AppDelegate` or `Tarbarcontroller` will crashes, but in the `Controller` will not crashes.
I want to take the window covering on the status bar, set the click event。

Crash Message:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'

Comment: see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884896/application-windows-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-a

Comment: may I ask why you want to initialize a new uiwindow object here?

Comment: @JohnTai I want to take the window covering on the status bar, set the click event。

Comment: you mean like :  ` - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    
    static UIWindow *window_;
    window_ = [[UIWindow alloc]init];
    window_.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20);
    window_.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
    window_.hidden = NO;
    
    UIViewController *VC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    VC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    window_.rootViewController = VC;
    [window_ makeKeyAndVisible];
    
    
    return YES;
} `

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thank you, I solved my problem.