# Error: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to update an iOS app written 6 years ago using `OpenGL` `ES` and `Objective C`.

When running the app as it is, I get this error:

> 4DRoom_v3[2360:42863] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'

From what I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884896/application-windows-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-a/%22here%22) I need to set the root view controller.

I add the subview here:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

[MeshViewAppDelegate globalVarInit];

//sleep(1);
glView.multipleTouchEnabled = TRUE;
load4Dice();//(str, NEW);

[window addSubview:glView];
//[window makeKeyAndVisible];
glView.animationFrameInterval = 1.0/40;
printf("finish luanching\n");
//[glView startAnimation];

return YES;
}
```

glView is a subclass of UIView. But I don't see how to implement the solution given since in this case, the view is not a property of a UIViewController.

It isn't clear to me what UIViewController I could set as the root view controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view controller and add your glview as subview:

```
UIViewController* vc = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[vc.view addSubview:glview];
window.rootViewController = vc;
```