# Terminating app due to uncaught exception reason: 'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'

Tags: ios

```
FeedContentVC *feedVC= [[FeedContentVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"FeedContentVC" bundle:nil];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:feedVC]; 
navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack; 
[window setRootViewController:navigationController];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520971/applications-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-applicati)

Answer (score 0):

Although things looks correct in what you are doing, could you please confirm following:

1. `window` is a strong property in your `AppDelegate`. It should be `[self.window setRootViewController:navigationController]`.
2. Put a breakpoint and check that `feedVC` is not nil.
3. You have this statement in your code `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        FeedContentVC *feedVC= [[FeedContentVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"FeedContentVC" bundle:nil];
        navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:feedVC]; 
navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
        [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
```