# libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Xcode 9 I kept getting this error when I load my app

> libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.

How to stop that?

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/103753 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701321/xcode-error-on-simulation/50724411

Comment: Most of the reports say this is "new in Xcode 10", can you double-check the Xcode version?

Comment: Needs more information. Are you using a real device to test or the simulator? Which iOS version, device model, etc.

Answer (score -2):

I'm studying iOS development with ObjC by an old book(for personal reasons), and this error happened when I override the **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** from **AppDelegate.m** so I Solved by setting a global *Navigation Controller*, like this:

```
 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    RootController *rootController = [[RootController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController  *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootController];

    self.window.rootViewController = navController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [rootController release];

    [navController release];

    return YES;
}
```

Xcode 10.0 (10A255)

Worked on iPhone and Simulator(Both iPhone 7 - iOS 12)