# Showing libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

When I try to use simulator, it's generating `libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType` error, while loading an app and showing exactly different of what I designed in storyboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51640360/libmobilegestalt-mobilegestalt-c890-mgisdeviceoneoftype-is-not-supported-on-th)