# Unable to look up screen scale and Unexpected physical screen orientation in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have recently updated Xcode to version 10, and now my console displays:

```
MyApp[1618:133310] [AXMediaCommon] Unable to look up screen scale
MyApp[1618:133310] [AXMediaCommon] Unexpected physical screen orientation
MyApp[1618:133310] [AXMediaCommon] Unable to look up screen scale
MyApp[1618:133310] [AXMediaCommon] Unable to look up screen scale
MyApp[1618:133310] [AXMediaCommon] Unexpected physical screen orientation
```

This only happens when I am running the app in the simulator. I have not changed my code since updating, and nothing appears to have broken in the app. What do these logs mean, and how can I resolve them?

Comment: Try to scale/zoom out (-) simulator's screen

Comment: scale/zoom failed to change the logs being output (for the iPhone 8 simulator I did zoom, 100%, 75%, and 50% with no effect on the logs).

Comment: I see the same logs on Xcode 10 with the ***iPhone XR*** simulator. No issues with ***iPhone X***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could sounds dummy, but these warning appeared me after move the simulator previously rendered from the Macbook screen, to a wider external screen.

I solved it just restarting the simulator in the external screen. My 2 cents.

Answer (score 17):

I've met the same problem. Finally I find out that this is because I accidentally resize the simulator's screen using my mouse cursor. By quiting and restarting the simulator my problem is solved.

Hope the aforementioned information helps.

Comment: No need to restart the simulator. You can do this pressing shortcut: cmd+1

Comment: had this problem, yes this fixed it for me, i just manually sized the simulator to max size, and then quit, and restarted and all logs didn't come back :)

Answer (score 9):

This won't answer your original question, but it might relieve your eyes. 
A **caveat** to this answer however is that it **disables all NSLog** statements.

Do the following to suppress - all NSLog statements including - the warning: `Unable to look up screen scale`:

[image: In Xcode, go to Product - Scheme - Edit Scheme, select 'Run' on the left side ...]

In Xcode, go to Product - Scheme - Edit Scheme, select 'Run' on the left side ...

[image: ... and add OS_ACTIVITY_MODE with value 'disable' in the 'Environment variables' section.]

... and add `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` with value "disable" in the `Environment variables` section.

Comment: Warnings are gone - thanks, but is it safe to set this Environment variable to `disable`. What about other possible log entries, exceptions, etc.?

Comment: what does it mean?

Comment: OS_ACTIVITY_MODE disables all NSLog statements, you should really include that as a big caveat for writing a answer like this.

Comment: This answer eliminates the symptom but is completely unhelpful in understanding the underlying problem. I wish I could down vote it more than once.

Comment: I'm going to link to this answer from another question. I'm going to edit the answer to reflect these comments.

Comment: Also related to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701321/xcode-error-on-simulation-mgisdeviceoneoftype-is-not-supported-on-this-platform

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue after running some UITest from a gitlab-runner.

The simulator got into this state and the only way to solve it was to go to **Hardware -> Erase all content and settings**

Answer (score 1):

Resizing the simulator's screen size to actual device size resolved this for me:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> is the shortcut.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the issue, when I was running on iOS 12.2 and MacOS Majove (Version 10.14.4)
Just change to iOS 11.4 and everything working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced something similar.  If restarting simulator doesn't do the trick, check your UI test code.  Make sure your `setup` calls `super.setup()` somewhere:

```
override func setup() {
    super.setup()
    // ....
}
```