# Table view still showing basic even after making it custom in Xcode 10.1

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10

I have done everything as done before in my previous projects in Xcode 8.1...
But simulator shows basic empty table rows even after making it custom.
tried everything including delegate and datasource in viewdidload.

Here's the project link
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hBR1cH5vr-sS4gLB-VBfF6iJPYKD59rd

(Sorry for that google drive upload)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tblNames: UITableView!

var names = ["lonrvc","ktbfse","lnrset"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()      
    self.tblNames.delegate = self
    self.tblNames.dataSource = self  
    self.tblNames.reloadData()   
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return names.count       
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {        
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomTableViewCell        
    cell.lblName.text = names[indexPath.row]
    self.tblNames.reloadData()        
    return cell
      }
  }
```

I just want to show the array on custom cell.(not on basic cell)

Comment: Why you are reloading tableview in cellForRowAt?

Comment: Agree, the `cellForRowAt` is called when the table reloads the data so you are basically creating an infinite loop.

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: Yes I am using storyboard.

Comment: I have shared my project link..please have look on it.

Comment: I think its part of Xcode 10.1 bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a look at your project, just set some constraints to your label in the storyboard and it should work fine, oh and delete the line `self.tblNames.reloadData()` from `cellForRowAt`.

[image]

Comment: Nope..this doesn't works at all...Kindly download my project and check please...please help me

Comment: I downloaded your project, and this is the only changes i made, and im running Xcode 10.1

Comment: at least run the app after the changes u suggested in your Xcode..please

Comment: I ran the app, and the names appeared.

Comment: sure hold on a minute

Comment: But in Xcode 8.1 I never used constraints and all to view

Comment: yeahhh...this worked...but is there any way to use it without constraints...sice I am a noob

Comment: No problem, but if you are using the interface builder (storyboard) why wouldn't you want constraints? your layout needs these constrains to match with all devices.

Comment: can u help me out with the error message showing libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.

Comment: But I never used constraints in Xcode 8.1 and previous versions.I am just a learner..so I don't have time for constraints and just want to lean code

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701321/xcode-error-on-simulation-mgisdeviceoneoftype-is-not-supported-on-this-platform, or feel free to open another question.

Comment: Dude there are no shortcuts, its a really important part of iOS development, you should learn it, also, you can use constraints in code since you prefer to code.

Comment: Okay dude...I really don't know how to thank u...u saved my time

Comment: Im glad I could help.