# MKAnnotation and firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a function to load my drivers location from firebase and place an annotations on their current locations but when I try to simulate to test the code it crashes. I've tried on both my phone and the Xcode simulator. Below is the code that keeps crashing my app.

```
func loadDriverAnnotationsFromFB() {
    DataService.instance.REF_DRIVERS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let driverSnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for drivers in driverSnapshot {
                if drivers.hasChild("userIsDriver") {
                    if drivers.hasChild("coordinate") {
                        if drivers.childSnapshot(forPath: "isPickupModeEnabled").value as? Bool == true {
                            if let driverDict = drivers.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                                let coordinatArray = driverDict["coordinate"] as! NSArray
                                let driverCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinatArray[0] as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: coordinatArray[1] as! CLLocationDegrees)

                                let driverAnnotation = DriverAnnotation(coordinate: driverCoordinate, withKey: drivers.key)

                                var driverIsVisible: Bool {
                                    return self.mapView.annotations.contains(where: { (annotation) -> Bool in
                                        if let driverAnnotation = annotation as? DriverAnnotation {
                                            if driverAnnotation.key == drivers.key {
                                                driverAnnotation.update(annotationPosition: driverAnnotation, withCoordinate: driverCoordinate)
                                                return true

                                            }



                                        }
                                        return false
                                    })

                                }
                                if !driverIsVisible {
                                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(driverAnnotation)
                                }

                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: If you app crashes, there is a stack trace somewhere showing the case of the crash. Please capture the exact error message and stack trace and add them to your question (it typically also helps to search for the error message, since somebody may have had it before). To capture the error message in xcode, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: when I build the app it builds successful but on the simulator it crashes

Comment: below is the error that I get in the console

Comment: 2019-01-10 21:52:55.923450-0500 PotiFy[3122:241748] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.
2019-01-10 21:52:58.069187-0500 PotiFy[3122:241748] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRAppNotConfigured', reason: 'Failed to get default Firebase Database instance. Must call `[FIRApp configure]` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) before using Firebase Database.'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: (
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010949f1bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108a3d735 objc_exception_throw + 48
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010949f015 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
 3   PotiFy                              0x0000000105de0228 +[FIRDatabase database] + 67
 4   PotiFy                              0x0000000105d11993 globalinit_33_E8A10CA2FDD27D46111C82758EABF4FF_func0 + 35

Comment: I have the FirebaseApp.configure() in my appDelegate and it keeps giving me this error.

Comment: Please add all additional information into your question, by clicking the `edit` link under it. That also allows you to format it, using the Stack Overflow formatting tools.

Comment: Firebase isn't the issue - *MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform* is the issue and it's a known problem; bottom line it's a compatibility between Xcode and the Simulator. Try it on a different Simulator, iPhone X for example and it will probably work. A quick google search will reveal a lot of information about this issue. Also see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701321/xcode-error-on-simulation-mgisdeviceoneoftype-is-not-supported-on-this-platform) for some specifics.