# Recording the movement of the user in 10 meter increments and displaying it as a line in MKMapView doesn’t work

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, core-location

I‘m a beginner trying to solve a problem in which I have to display the location path of the user every ten meters after the user hits ‚start‘.

I‘ve set up the location manager. The location is being updated, the problem is that it doesn't show a visual path between the starting point and the current user location.

How do I show the visual path?

I tried to calculate the route with MKDirectionsRequest and -Response and it worked well with two given locations, which in this case I don't have though. I also tried the MKMapPoints but to be honest it isn't the point of our homework, in that it would make it unnecessarily complicated.

Here is my current state:

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {

    CLLocation *newLocation;
    newLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude) altitude:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters horizontalAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters verticalAccuracy:newLocation.verticalAccuracy timestamp:newLocation.timestamp];
    newLocation = [locations lastObject];

    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) {
        return;
    }

    NSInteger count = [locations count];

    if (count > 1) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[count];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            coordinates[i] = [(CLLocation *)locations[i] coordinate];
        }
        MKPolyline *polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:count];
        [self.mapView addOverlay:polyline level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
    }

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.wegAnnotation.coordinate, 200, 200);
    [mapView setRegion:region];

    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    self.myLocationManager = nil;

}

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
    MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    renderer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    renderer.lineWidth = 5.0;
    return renderer;
}
```

Comment: Hi Anna, there are multiple solutions already on the platform one thread being: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701321/xcode-error-on-simulation-mgisdeviceoneoftype-is-not-supported-on-this-platform. A search for `MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.` also will help :), as the error message suggests.

Comment: This part of the error message is not the issue I think. I get this type of error in unrelated circumstances. The core issue is detailed in my description. But thanks for the help!

Comment: You are getting a crash because `locations.polyline` doesn't contain any points.  Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkroute) - you shouldn't create an instance of `MKRoute`; you should retrieve the route from your directions request. If you want to show a location where the user has been rather than a route they are to follow then you will need to use Core Location to receive location updates and create your own MKPolyLine with each additional location

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. At least the app doesn’t crash any more. But unfortunately I still don’t get the visual path. I’ve got rid of MKRoute and the showRoute method in general and created MKPolyline in the didUpdateLocation method. I've edited my code in the initial question for my current state. Hope I'm making progress, thanks!